# Как включить стандартную палитру в Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

Как включить стандартную палитру в Photoshop? А то у меня палитра без полного кода цвета.

У меня палитра вот так отображается
[image]

Как вернуть стандартную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, о чем говорит автор.
Если настройки отображения colourpicker, то ctrl+k, там.
Если настройки отображения палитры справа, то Window->...

Comment: Edit > Preferences > General -> colorpicker -> adobe 
Не?

Comment: Не подходит. Тоже самое.

Comment: Стоп. А зачем же вы 32битный (16/32 бит/канал) документ открыли? =) В нем 16ричных цветов не будет.
Image->color mode

Comment: Спасибо, Вам большое!!! С меня полагается.

Comment: С меня полагается.// галочка? =)